# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (3000,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm playing with this https://vgpena.github.io/classifying-tweets-with-keras-and-tensorflow/ model and trying to make a Twitter sentiment analysis model. I'm getting

```
  File "C:\Users\sam\Desktop\proje\load_model.py", line 71, in <module>
    pred = model.predict(top_tweets)

  File "C:\Users\sam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1441, in predict
    x, _, _ = self._standardize_user_data(x)

  File "C:\Users\sam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 579, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "C:\Users\sam\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 145, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (3000,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I've searched and it seems like there is a problem with my model but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue

My code:

model.py:

```
import json
import keras
import keras.preprocessing.text as kpt
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

training = np.genfromtxt('training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv', delimiter=',', skip_header=1, usecols=(0, 5), dtype=None, encoding='latin-1')

train_x = [x[1] for x in training]
train_y = np.asarray([x[0] for x in training])

max_words = 3000

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_x)

dictionary = tokenizer.word_index
with open('dict.json', 'w') as dictionary_file:
    json.dump(dictionary, dictionary_file)


def convert_text_to_index_array(text):
    return [dictionary[word] for word in kpt.text_to_word_sequence(text)]


allWordIndices = []
for text in train_x:
    wordIndices = convert_text_to_index_array(text)
    allWordIndices.append(wordIndices)

allWordIndices = np.asarray(allWordIndices)

train_y = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(allWordIndices, mode='binary')
train_x = keras.utils.to_categorical(train_x, 2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_x, train_y,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=5,
          verbose=1,
          validation_split=0.1,
          shuffle=True)

model_json = model.to_json()
with open('model.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights('model.h5')

print('Model saved!')
```

load_model.py:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import keras.preprocessing.text as kpt
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import model_from_json
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import ndarray
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd


def get_tweets(username, top_only, max_tweets):
    tweet_criteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setUsername(username) \
        .setTopTweets(top_only) \
        .setMaxTweets(max_tweets)

    tweet = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweet_criteria)

    text_tweets = [[tw.text] for tw in tweet]

    top_tweets = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets)

    return top_tweets


tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=3000)
labels = ['negative', 'pozitive']

with open('dict.json', 'r') as dictionary_file:
    dictionary = json.load(dictionary_file)

    
def convert_to_index_array(text):
    words = kpt.text_to_word_sequence(text)
    wordIndices = []
    for word in words:
        if word in dictionary:
            wordIndices.append(dictionary[word])
        else:
            print(("'%s' is getting ignored." % (word)))
    return wordIndices


json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model.load_weights('model.h5')

while True:
    username = input("Enter an username:")
    top_tweets = get_tweets(username,
                            top_only=True,
                            max_tweets=100)
    evalSentence = top_tweets

    if len([input]) < 1:
        break

    testArr = convert_to_index_array(evalSentence.to_string())
    username = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix([testArr], mode="binary")
    pred = model.predict(top_tweets)
    print(("Your profile %s; %f%% confidince" % (labels(np.argmax(pred)), pred[0][np.argmax(pred)] * 100)))
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should preprocess your text to the actual input size. It's not clear what  Tokenizer returns but it is probably returning a tuple of size 1. Perhaps use text_data_set_from_directory?

Comment: @NelsonGon thank you for your answer! But I can't seem to find a function or attribute named "text_data_set_from_directory"

Comment: It's [dataset`](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/text/) not data_set(used to snake case too much) but I don't think it will help you.